# How to use the eval statement in (g)awk?

Tags: awk

Due to that awk does not seem to have callbacks, I was planning to use the eval statement for this. So I had a look at the GNU user guide,

https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Viewing-And-Changing-Data.html

and then wrote this simple script.

```
BEGIN {
    args[1]="\"a\""
    args[2]="\"b\""
    args[3]="\"c\""
    args[4]="\"\""
    run_callback("printargs",args)
    print args[4]
}
function run_callback(callback,args)
{
    nargs=length(args)
    if (nargs>0)
    {   
        argstring=args[1]
        for (argn=2;argn<=nargs;argn++)
        {
            argstring=argstring","args[argn]
        }
    }   
    callbackstr = callback"("argstring")"
    print callbackstr
    eval callbackstr
}
function printargs(arg1,arg2,arg3,res)
{
    res=arg1","arg2","arg3
    print "res="res
}
```

However, the printout is not what I expected. I get this,

```
[~]-> gawk -f callback.awk
printargs(a,b,c,"")
""
```

And not the expected,

```
[~]-> gawk -f callback.awk
printargs(a,b,c,"")
res=a,b,c
"Not sure what is supposed to be here, but it is not relevant."
```

It feels as if nothing actually happens inside the eval statement. Anyone who knows what happens here?

gawk version is 4.1.3

BR
Patrik

Comment: The documentation talks about `eval awk '..'` and not `eval` inside `awk`, enough to conclude `eval` is a  built-in provided by the shell and supported inside `awk`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's in the documentation for the gawk **debugger**. It's not a normal gawk function.

However, gawk *does* support calling a function whose name is in a string with the `@var(args,...)` notation ([More information in the documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Indirect-Calls.html)):

```
BEGIN {
    args[1]="a"
    args[2]="b"
    args[3]="c"
    args[4]="\"\""
    run_callback("printargs",args[1],args[2],args[3],args[4])
    print args[4]
}
function run_callback(callback,arg1,arg2,arg3,res)
{
    @callback(arg1,arg2,arg3,res);
}
function printargs(arg1,arg2,arg3,res)
{
    res=arg1","arg2","arg3
    print "res="res
}
```

when run will print out

```
res=a,b,c
""
```

Note that `args[4]` isn't modified from this. From [the documentation on function argument passing convention](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Pass-By-Value_002fReference.html):

> Instead, the passing convention is determined at runtime when the function is called, according to the following rule: if the argument is an array variable, then it is passed by reference. Otherwise, the argument is passed by value.

If you passed `args` directly and modified elements of it in the callback, you'd see the changes reflected.

Comment: `++` Nice! didn't know gawk had such a feature

Comment: Thanks! I had no idea this was possible. This is also an even better solution than eval would have been.

Answer (score 2):

awk doesn't have any `eval` keyword.

This can be check with gawk `--dump-variables` option

```
gawk --dump-variables -f callback.awk
```

It outputs the file `awkvars.out` and you'll find in it:

```
eval: uninitialized scalar
```